# If $f$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$ and $f'(x) \ne 0$ for each $x \in [a,b]$ so $f$ is monotone in $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $f$ is differentiable in $[a,b]$ and $f'(x) \ne 0$ for each $x \in [a,b]$ so $f$ is monotone in $[a,b]$.

Is this correct? I don't think so. Because the differntial doesn't have to be continuous so it can be positive in one area and negative in other... but I can't find a counter-example...

thanks

Comment: If $f$ is not monotonic, there are distinct $c$ and $d$  in $[a,b]$ (assumed non-degenerate) with $f(c)=f(d)$. Use Rolle's Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Darboux's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29), every derivative satisfies the intermediate value theorem (even though it may not be continuous).

Hence, either $f' > 0$ or $f' < 0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 6):

By [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function), we have that $f'$ is a Darboux function, i.e. maps full intervals to full intervals, in other words, it guarantees that the range of $f'$,
$f'([a,b])$ is a *full interval* which now avoids $0$, hence it lies on either the positive or the negative ray.